# How to change links of each tab when It's change using react ant design?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, antd

I'm using Ant Design Tab but my requirement is I want to change the link when we go each tab.Below is the my code . But here when I click to second tab it's showing blank page. Content of tab is not displaying. Can anyone suggest me the solution please?

Code:

```
const TabContainer =()=>{

 const handleTabClick =(key) => {
  history.push(`/${key}`)   
  
  }

  render = () => (
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="history" onChange={handleTabClick}>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="history">History</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="math">Math</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="science">Science</TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  )
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code and it should work as-is. However,  to debug more can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) somewhere in codesandbox or jsfiddle?

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: Yes I'm using react-router.

Comment: created a sandbox and tried to simulate your example - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-johnson-d6t3r?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control active tab with url/history, use `activeKey`. `defaultActiveKey` only defines a starting point

```
const TabContainer =()=> {
  const handleTabClick =(key) => {
    history.push(`/${key}`)   
  }

  render = () => (
    <Tabs activeKey={location.pathname.slice(1)} onChange={handleTabClick}>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="history">History</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="math">Math</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="science">Science</TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

Comment: Still for second tab  content is not displaying . 2nd tab url :http://localhost:3006/#/2, 1st tab url http://localhost:3006/#/dashboard/studies